# Prolog list of "lists" with only one element

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching

I have a recursive predicate call, and the output of that call is appended to a list with `append/3`. So the output is going to be a list of lists. My problem is, that sometimes the `append/3` gets called something like this:

```
append([[2]], [1,2,3,4], L).
```

And the output of this is `[[2], 1,2,3,4]`. I would like to check before the `append/3` that the first element is a list of lists with only one element, but so far I was unable to create a pattern that matches it.

So my question is: how can I check if something is a list of a list?

Comment: `A` is a list of exactly one list iff `A = [[]]] ; A = [[_|_]]` is true. `A` is a list of exactly one list of one element iff `A = [[_]]` is true.

Comment: @lurker `A=[[_]]` would be true for a list of lists of lists with any number of elements as well, e.g. `[[[1,2,3,4,5]]]` ([demo](http://ideone.com/oCnvav)). I am not sure if OP wanted to match such lists.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah yes you're right. And `A = [[_|_]]` could have further nesting as well..

Answer (score 1):

The rule that matches a Prolog *atom* is, well, [`atom/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom/1):

```
is_list_of_list_with_one_element([[X]]) :- atom(X).
```